# Generators for fake projective planes groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is there a reference for generators of fundamental groups of (some) fake projective planes in terms of matrices in $SU(2,1)$?

Comment: I think Cartwright and Steger have computed generators for all fake projective planes. It would probably be simplest to ask one of then.